# QuickBlox: Chatrooms ordered by recently exchanged messages

Tags: ios, sdk, quickblox

Using QuickBlox iOS SDK, I need to get the list of chatrooms ordered by latest modifications_ chatroom was receiving messages from users _without having to join each rooms to get latest messages and compare dates of latest messages inside them.

The Question may be said as, I need to know which chatrooms had been modified , date for last modification, since I have logged out last time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature available for now.
Currently we are working on it.